# Grouping the dataframe by categories and converting the results into a nested list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I am trying to convert the following dataframe:

```
cat  userid  val
1    1       10
1    2       15
1    3       22
2    1       33
2    2       54
2    3       44
```

to the following format: `[[10, 15, 22], [33, 54, 44]]`

This is my code:

```
df.groupby(['cat', 'userid'])['val'].apply(list)
```

And, this is what I get:

```
cat          userid
1            1          [10]
             2          [15]
             3          [22]
2            1          [33]
             2          [54]
             3          [44]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: use `df.groupby('cat')['val'].apply(list).tolist()`

Comment: @Zero sorry it was a mistake. corrected.

Comment: Duplicate of [grouping rows in list in pandas groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219004/grouping-rows-in-list-in-pandas-groupby) and [how extract a vector from groupby pandas in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43210427/how-extract-a-vector-from-groupby-pandas-in-python) and [Grouping in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31901506/grouping-in-pandas)

Comment: Ya, 2.nd and 3.rd is OK, first not. So deleting answer.

Comment: Ya, it is sad ;) I am working on it.